# How do I create a dynamic web page for a client pulling from my database

Tags: web, privacy

I have a business idea where clients would enter some information in on a Software as a service type interface by filling out some web forms.  The information they entered in would then be saved to my database.  I am comfortable with this part, however I would like to be able to have clients put a small almost stupidly simple code snippet on their web page and be able to push content to their web page in a content div.  I guess I could just send them a .php file to upload to their root and a single include line to write but I would prefer not to do this sort of thing since I don't really want to be mailing out proprietary code snippets with my DB information.

Are there any suggestions for how to implement the content push that are both extremely simple for clients to put on a web page but at the same time very private in the way the code is pushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question really well but...

Isn't the answer to your problem a webservice? You could create a webservice that receives some sort of "password" and if the password is right you return the data JSON/XML formatted.

But you are talking about push, that means that when your server have new information you want to notify your client's server about the new information. I would say that what you should do in that case is make a request to the client server notifying them that you have "new stuff" and then after they have been notified they simply go ahead and use your webservice (mentioned above) and update their data.

I hope this answer your question or gives you and idea of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks this sounds like what I was looking for.